Does $R/I\cong R/J$ as $R$-modules imply $I=J$ when $R$ is not commutative?
Let $R$ be a commutative ring, and $I$ and $J$ ideals of $R$. Equip $R/I$ and $R/J$ with their natural $R$-module structures, then if $R/I\cong R/J$ as $R$-modules we have that $I=J$. Indeed, if $\phi:R/I\rightarrow R/J$ is an $R$-module map, then for all $j\in J$ we have that $\phi([j])=j\cdot \phi([1])=0$. It follows that $j\cdot [1]=[j]=0\in R/I$, so $J\subset I$. Applying the same argument to the inverse gives us that $I\subset J$ so $I=J$.
Does this argument somehow fail when $R$ is noncommuative and $I$ and $J$ are left modules? If so I cannot see where...
I ask because in a commutative Artinian ring there are finitely many maximal ideals, but according to this the equivalent statement for a left Artinian ring is that there are finitely many isomorphism classes of simple left modules. However, all simple left modules are of the form $R/\mathfrak{m}$ where $\mathfrak{m}$ is a left maximal ideal. If the above holds in the non commutative case then there should only be finitely many maximal left ideals as well right? So there has to be some $\mathfrak{m}$ and some $\mathfrak{n}$ such that $R/\mathfrak m\cong R/\mathfrak n$ as left $R$ modules, but $\mathfrak{m}\neq \mathfrak{n}$.
Edit:
I can even think of a counter example. If $R=M_2(\mathbb R)$, and $\{e_1,e_2\}$ is the standard basis, then $I=\{A\in R:Ae_1=0\}$ and $J=\{A\in R:Ae_2=0\}$ are maximal left ideals, and their quotients are the simple $R$-modules $\mathbb R^2$ with the standard $M_2(\mathbb R)$ structure on it so they are trivially isomorphic. However $I\neq J$...so surely something is wrong with the proof in the first paragraph when we drop the fact that $R$ is commutative. The proof just seems like it carries over almost verbatim though so I don't see what's wrong.

If $J$ is a left ideal that is not also a right ideal, then $j \cdot \phi([1]_I)$ need not be $0$, as one could have $\phi([1]_I)=[r]_J$ with $jr \notin J$ (using subscripts to disambiguate elements of $R/I$ and $R/J$).

I see, that pretty much clears up this now very silly question, so if you would like to post this as answer I will accept it

If $I$ and $J$ are left (or right) ideals that are not two-sided ideals, then $R/I \cong R/J$ (as left or right $R$-modules) need not imply $I=J$, unlike in the two-sided case, where taking annihilators ($\mathrm{Ann}(R/I)=\mathrm{Ann}(R/J)$) suffices to show that $I=J$. The part of your argument that does not apply if $J$ is a one-sided ideal is the equation $\phi([j])=j\cdot \phi([1])=0$.
For example, for the ring $R=\mathbb{R}\langle x, x^{-1}, y \rangle$ (where $y$ does not commute with $x$), $R/Ry$ and $R/Ryx$ are isomorphic as left $R$-modules via right multiplication by $x$, but $Ry \ne Ryx$.
