Characterization of quotient module over maximal ideals
Let $R$ be a ring (not necessarily commutative), and $A$ and $B$ be maximal ideals of $R$. I have to prove the following statement:
$$R/A \cong R/B \ \text{as modules over} \ R \ \text{if and only if there exists an} \ r \in R \setminus B \ \text{such that} \ rA \subset B.$$
For the $\implies$ implication, I have the following proof:
Let $f:R/B \rightarrow R/A$ be a module isomorphism. I will now show that $A \subset B$ (which then automatically implies that there exists an $r \in R \setminus B$ such that $rA \subset B$, namely $r = 1 \notin B$). First notice that $f(1+B) \in R/A$, so $f(1+B) = r + A$ for some $r \in R$. Now take $x \in A$. Then we have
\begin{align*} 
f(x + B) & = f(x \cdot (1+B)) \\
& = x \cdot f(1+B) \\
& = x \cdot (r+A) \\
& = xr +A .
\end{align*}
But because $A$ is an ideal, we have $xr \in A$ and thus $xr + A = A$. This implies that $x + B \in \ker f$. Because $f$ is an injective module homomorphism, we know that $\ker f$ is trivial, and thus $x+ B = B$. So $x \in B$. $\square$
However, for the other implication, I cannot seem to find an explicit module isomorphism between the two quotients. I tried playing around with the following module homomorphism:
\begin{align*}
f:R/A \rightarrow R/B: x+A \rightarrow xr + B
\end{align*}
which seems to be well-defined because of the assumption $rA \subset B$, but I cannot seem to prove that it is injective and surjective.
I also find it odd that for my proof of $\implies$ I was able to show that $A \subset B$, because in the same way I should be able to show that $B \subset A$ with the inverse image. This would mean that $R/A \cong R/B$ as $R$-modules would imply that $A = B$ for any two ideals $A,B$ (not even maximal ideals is needed because I didn't use maximality in my proof of $\implies$). So I was wondering if my proof is correct, or maybe I would have to use maximality for the other implication but I don't know how.
Thanks in advance!
Edit: For the $\implies$ implication, right ideal is needed. For the other implication, it seems that maximal left ideal is needed (meaning that $A,B$ would have to be maximal elements of the poset of proper left ideals). So I suspect an error in the formulation of the problem. This problem was given in the course notes of my professor, and we have never been introduced to the notion of maximal left ideals (only to maximal ideals, i.e. two-sided ideals that are maximal amongst all two-sided ideals).

Are you sure they are actual ideals, and not just left ideals?

@Mark Yes they are maximal ideals, meaning two sided ideals that are maximal. Why ?

Because if you knew they are maximal left ideals, the homomorphism you defined in the second direction would immediately be an isomorphism by Schur's lemma.

@Mark Oh I see, we do not know beforehand that $R/A$ is a simple module because the correspondence theorem for modules only works for left ideals in this case, so we cannot use Schur's lemma. Is that what you mean ?

Does this dupe answer your question? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4966322 If not, please edit your question accordingly.

I assume the exercise actually wants to talk about maximal left ideals? Where does it come from? Please edit to clarify the context.

@MartinBrandenburg Yes it would seem like the exercise should be talking about maximal left ideals. However for my proof of the $\implies$ implication to work, right ideal is needed, which confuses me?
